# php move a file based on part of its name or file type

Tags: php

Hi I have a system that saves a file and uses the date and time as part of the file name. 
This runs from a cron, every hour or so when it runs I would like to move the last generated file to another folder and save the next one.

I am have trouble identifying the file though due to the change of name as a result of the date.

How do I identify this file? , I was thinking of trying to identify it by cutting out the date but im not so sure if thats efficient. Im also ok with the idea of finding the only CSV file in the folder and moving that.

Currently the error Im getting is that its not finding the file which is expected.

```
$date = date('Y-m-j-H-i-s');
rename(DIR_IMAGE . 'latest-orders-'.$date.'.csv', DIR_IMAGE . '/orders-archive/latest-orders-'.$date.'.csv');


// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(DIR_IMAGE . 'latest-orders-'.$date.'.csv');
```

Thank you

Comment: Ok I just realised I can add the date after the move, oops!

Comment: Is your file called `latest-orders-2014-02-27-17-46-15.csv`?

Comment: for now yes, this was going to be cleaned up, but it just occured to me that when Im archiving it I can add the date as opposed to saving the date on the normal file.

Comment: @Adrian What you have struck on is how typical log rotation tasks work.  Look at your webserver access logs for example.  They would typically always work with a base file (for example `access.log`) and then when the log file is being rotated, the date/time data is appended to the name of the file being archived, while the new empty file retains the same name.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That sorted the issue alright